How Can I Clear Cookies for my Web Application Using Javascript?
I have an ASP.NET web application built with .NET Framework 4.6.2. This application logs users into their accounts for a separate engineering application to display data in a web interface. When users click a logout button, they are redirected to a logout page. Behind the scenes, their session for the engineering application is cleared. However, I also need to clear the cookies for the web application when the logout page loads.
The first thing I did was determine what path the cookies for my website were being stored. They were being stored in the / path.
Next, I added the following javascript to my logout.aspx page:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;';
    }

    function clearAllCookies() {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        cookies.forEach(cookie => {
            const cookieName = cookie.split('=')[0].trim();
            deleteCookie(cookieName);
            deleteCookie(cookieName, "/");
        });
    }
    //Clear cookies on logout
    window.onload = function () {
        clearAllCookies();
    }
</script>

I pushed this updated code to my test server, and when I clicked my logout button, I navigated to chrome://settings/content/all and saw that the cookie for my website was still there. Is there a more effective way that I can clear the cookies for my web application?

are your cookies httpOnly? Why do you call deleteCookie(cookieName, "/"); when deleteCookie only takes a single argument?

Maybe also check if the cookie names have non-alpha numeric characters? You may have to uriDecode the names? And like Jaromanda mentioned, httpOnly cookies can not be read/overwritten by javascript, you'll have to do the cookie clearing from the server that set them.

This code snippet cleared the cookies for my website upon loading my logout page.
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // Clear cookies for Drawing Viewer upon logout
    if (Request.Cookies != null)
    {
        var cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(cookie)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                Value = string.Empty
            };
            Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
        }
    }
}

